# Problem when I try to do a data refresh

Tags: error, powerpivot, troubleshooting, data-refresh

I'm having trouble with data PowerPivot data refresh...

I have made 2 workbooks:

1 - Put some random data, to use this workbook as a data source. I put it on SharePoint server PowerPivot gallery... `(http://spserver/data/model.xls)`

2 - I made another workbook, select data source `(http://spserver/data/model.xls)`
put some dynamic table... and work with data.

When the second workbook is on my desktop... I can work with it without a problem.

But, when I put the workbook on SharePoint `(http://spserver/reports/report01.xls)` and access this via Excel Web App... I can't filter data, can't update anything... so... not working.

The error:

> Access was denied by the external data source. The following
>   connections failed to refresh: mycustom datasource

Where can I found error log? Windows Log Event ?! How can I troubleshoot this type of error?

Comment: Which sharepoint server version are you using and which powerpivot version?

Comment: I was wondering how you expect the security to work, what authentication. Have you considered using a connection library?

Comment: You had me thinking that I hadn't used a data connection library for a while, so I did some checking. I was also curious about the Web App.

Comment: Before I was interrupted.. Check the SharePoint Online Help, the Web App will not refresh from another workbook model.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot these errors by looking at the SP logs of your farm

normally : C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\ 14 , or 15, or 16  \logs\

you can then review this logs in real time using ULSviewer.

but first you have to enable logging in your sharepoint farm:

central Admin> monitoring > Diagnostic logging